# I'd like to update the menu_order field by an increment of 1 front end dynamically by product ID?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

To update the database field in wordpress I currently have the following in the function.php file.

```
`$update_args = array(
'ID' => '123',
'menu_order' => '19'
);
$result = wp_update_post($update_args);`
```

This only updates the product id '123' and sets it to '19'. What I need it to do is update any product id when the page is viewed by an increment of 1 typically as below.

```
$menu_order++;
```

Works fine updating fixed values but need it to work dynamically when each product viewed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
Something like this would work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'your_prefix_woocommerce_after_single_product' );
function your_prefix_woocommerce_after_single_product(  ) {
   global $product;
   $id = $product->get_id();
   // do stuff with the product
}
```

Add this to your child-theme `functions.php`.
It only runs on single-product page.

Comment: Brilliant! Works a treat.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. You can set it as accepted answer so it's closed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked by OP. The question was about updating menu_order meta dynamically and not about doing some stuff after product is displayed